# Reservoir sampling: evict specific items from stream?

Tags: bigdata

In Reservoir sampling algorithm, we always evict random items from a stream.

Is there a way to evict smallest sample items (instead of random items)?

What are ways to do that?

Comment: What analysis are you performing on the sample afterwards? e.g. if you always evict the lowest value then that would skew any average you produce I'd expect.

Comment: I reworded your question to make it more readable. Please review my changes, and see if they work for you.